# How to create SAS EG Flow programmatically?

Tags: vb.net, sas, enterprise-guide

I write a solution which manages execution of complex calculations written in heterogeneous environments (R, SAS, Oracle). One of the features I might want to add is the ability to create a nice SAS Enterprise Guide flow using the SAS branches of the execution, using the exposed COM (that is based on the .NET) interface.

I thought I can use [SASEGScripting](http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/guide/SASEGScripting41.zip) to insert SAS code and link the code according to their dependency that my solution already manages.

I can insert the code object, but unfortunately I don't know how to create a link.

Using the techniques from [ExtractCodeAndLog.vbs.txt](http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/guide/examples/SASGF2012/ExtractCodeAndLog.vbs.txt)
I can get an existing link between two flow items using `set item = myproject.ContainerCollection.Item` and `item.Items`. If I iterate through the Items collection, I would get links, and would be able to inspect their properties.

Comment: Thank you Adam for your question. I'm following this.

Comment: Only suggestion I have is see if Chris Hemedinger has any ideas - he has a blog (["The SAS Dummy"](http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/) and posts regularly on communities.sas.com.  I don't know if he comes here much or not.  He's pretty much the EG scripting guru (and works for SAS).

Answer (score 1):

In your EG project, right click on the object you want to make the link from and select 'Link' this will show you the list of possible object to link to. just select one from them.

Example:

Step 1

[image: link1]

Step 2

[image: link2]

Step 3

[image: link3]